# Why is it so difficult to create a setup that provides the user with just a Setup.exe in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone have a full example of providing a clickonce install that provide the user with a Setup.exe.

This should be simple!

Clickonce is not a solution the user does not want to see loads of files in a folder; he/she wants a simple setup.exe.

The msi setup wizard seems not to be hooked up to the clickonce system.

There is some info about a bootstrap thing but again that is an addon :(

Comment: the goal of clickonce is different than standard legacy setups. what kind of setup do you want ? The answer to this question will help you to choose between two worlds.

Comment: have you tried InstallShield?

Comment: This looks more like a rant than a question. ClickOnce is a very different technology with a very different focus than a traditional installer. But Visual Studio has support for utilizing either. Update your question to ask for instructions, rather than complain about your misunderstandings if you want help.

Comment: Sorry it was a bit of a rant. I was so annoyed after spending days trying create a setup for a beta winform app that I could send to a tester! But I did want an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user wants a web delivery of a setup.exe, then create a setup project in Visual Studio (see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353) for instructions) and then post the setup.exe on a web site for the user to download.

This will not have the ability to update the application, which is one of the primary differences from clickonce.

If you want this functionality, then you will either have to create it yourself (we did and it took approximately 3 weeks) or purchase a third party installer package such as [Installshield](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm).

If you can afford it, I strongly recommend this approach since they have streaming setups, web sites for hosting the installs, and support.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I now know that I'm trying to use the wrong tool "ClickOnce" and should focus my efforts on getting the setup project thing working.